# How do I spawn a JVM from a JVM that is easy to control and monitor?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to span a new JVM process from a Java class.

I could use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` but this is a very low level api.

I am looking for something that will wrap that `Process` api for me in something a bit more convenient like:

```
MonitoredJavaProcess javaProcess = new MonitoredJavaProcess(MyMainClass.class, "-Xmx1g");
javaProcess.getGcLogStream();
javaProcess.getHeapSizeObserver();
// ...
javaProcess.waitForShutdown();
```

A bit context on what I am trying to do: I am running JUnit a test suite taht starts up an embedded Jetty server and runs some test against it. That means that the tested Jetty server threads and the junit test threads run in the same JVM. I need to run them i separate JVMs. I could use ant or maven or anything external to starup jetty and then run the test suite against it but it sound a bit of an overkill for my simple scenario.

Comment: Maybe [javamelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/) (a JVM monitoring tool) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your approach is not the right one. Perhaps you should consider using [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html) to monitor your JVMs instead?

Cheers,

Comment: A bit context on what I am trying to do: I am running JUnit a test suite taht starts up an embedded Jetty server and runs some test against it. That means that the tested Jetty server threads and the junit test threads run in the same JVM. I need to run them i separate JVMs. I could use ant or maven or anything external to starup jetty and then run the test suite against it but it sound a bit of an overkill for my simple scenario.

Comment: OK, not sure I understand why you need a separate JVM but I still think JMX is a good choice for measuring performance in your scenario.

Comment: I need the separate JVM to measure CPU and Memory and GC stats of production code. I do not want the JUnit test thread to have any influence on the performance reports. Those JUnit tests use a lot of memory and CPU themselvs as well.

I decided to wrap the `ProcessBuilder` and JMX in a class `JettyServerInseparateJvm` that does the process handlinmg and exposes JMX stats via metods as well.

Answer (score 2):

What actually you are trying to do. 
May be you can look at [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) it might suite your need.

Comment: A bit context on what I am trying to do: I am running JUnit a test suite taht starts up an embedded Jetty server and runs some test against it. That means that the tested Jetty server threads and the junit test threads run in the same JVM. I need to run them i separate JVMs. I could use ant or maven or anything external to starup jetty and then run the test suite against it but it sound a bit of an overkill for my simple scenario.

Comment: `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` is prvides a little bit more functionality but is still far from what I am looking for unfortunately.